# Deadlocks in linked list with hand over locking

Tags: c, mutex

I'm trying to create simple concurrent linked list (as exercise from OS 3 easy pieces book) , where for traversal it uses hand over locking  - eg. each node has it's own lock and in traversal next node lock is acquired just before this node lock is release.

And I do have some problem in code- o I'm getting a deadlock, but I'm not exactly sure why - deadlock is on lock for next node in `list_find` line 87.

Could somebody please explain me what exactly is the problem? I've been playing a while with code, using also helgrind, adding debug prints, but cannot somehow find where is problem.

Thanks.

**Code updated** based on provided, but still getting deadlock.

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "measure.h"
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct __node_t
{
    int value;
    struct __node_t *next;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} node_t;

typedef struct __list_t
{
    node_t *head;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;

} list_t;

void list_init(list_t *list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&list->lock, NULL);
}

void list_insert(list_t *list, int value)
{
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    if (new == NULL)
    {
        perror("Allocation error:");
        return;
    }

    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&new->lock, NULL);
    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&list->lock) == 0);
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = new;
    }
    else
    {

        //assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&new->lock) == 0);

        new->next = list->head;
        list->head = new;
        //pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
        //printf("Thread %d - inserted %d\n", tid, list->head->value);
        //assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&new->lock) == 0);
    }
    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&list->lock) == 0);
}

int list_find(list_t *list, int value)
{
    int rv = -1;

    if (list->head == NULL)
        return rv;

    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&list->head->lock) == 0);
    node_t *current = list->head;
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    while (current != NULL)
    {

        printf("Thread %d - comparing %d to %d\n", tid, current->value, value);
        if (current->value == value)
        {
            rv = 0;
            assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&current->lock) == 0);
            printf("Thread %d - unlocked current %d (on match)\n", tid, current->value);
            break;
        }
        node_t *next = current->next;
        if (next != NULL)
        {
            printf("Thread %d - want to lock next %d\n", tid, next->value);
            assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&next->lock) == 0);
            printf("Thread %d - locked next %d\n", tid, next->value);
        }
        assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&current->lock) == 0);
        printf("Thread %d - unlocked current %d\n", tid, current->value);
        current = next;
    }

    return rv;
}

void list_clear(list_t *list)
{

    if (list->head != NULL)
    {

        assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&list->head->lock) == 0);
        node_t *current = list->head;
        list->head = NULL;
        assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&current->lock) == 0);

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            //assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&current->lock) == 0);
            node_t *next = current->next;
            free(current);
            //assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&current->lock) == 0);
            current = next;
        }
    }
}

#define LIMIT 1000
#define NUM_THREADS 2

struct worker_params
{
    list_t *list;
    int thread_no;
};

void *worker(void *arg)
{
    struct worker_params *params = (struct worker_params *)arg;
    list_t *list = params->list;
    int thread_no = params->thread_no;
    for (int i = 0 + thread_no * LIMIT; i < LIMIT + thread_no * LIMIT; i++)
    {
        list_insert(list, i);
    }
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    //printf("Thread %d - All inserted\n", tid);
    for (int i = 0 + thread_no * LIMIT; i < LIMIT + thread_no * LIMIT; i++)
    {
        printf("Thread %d - to find %d\n", tid, i);
        assert(list_find(list, i) == 0);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    list_t list;
    list_init(&list);

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    struct worker_params params[NUM_THREADS];

    Timer timer;
    timer_start(&timer);

    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
    {
        params[j].list = &list;
        params[j].thread_no = j;
        assert(pthread_create(&threads[j], NULL, worker, (void *)&params[j]) == 0);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
    {
        assert(pthread_join(threads[j], NULL) == 0);
    }

    timer_stop(&timer);
    printf("%d iterations took %lld us\n", LIMIT, timer_get_us(&timer));
    list_clear(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem inside `list_insert`. The function leaves closed mutexes.

You protect adding to the list using the `list->head->lock` lock. However, inside the function you replace `list->head` itself. So, the second thread will not wait on `list->head->lock`, but on the `new->lock` you just inserted. You need to protect the section using a lock that is accessible by both threads at all times.

Also doing:

```
if (list->head == NULL)
{
    list->head = new;
```

is a race condition. If both threads will execute concurrently at the same time, both will check that `list->head` is null and both will try to write `list->head = new`. This leaks memory, as one threads wins and in one of the threads the value of `new` is overwritten by the other threads.

To summarize, the locking in `list_insert` is done improperly.

Using a simple list-global list lock:

```
typedef struct __list_t
{
    node_t *head;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} list_t;

...

void list_insert(list_t *list, int value)
{
    ....
    pthread_mutex_init(&new->lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&list->lock);
    if (list->head == NULL)
    ...
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list->lock);
}
```

will resolve the issue.

Notes:

- identifiers with double `__` underscores are reserved by the C standard.
- expressions in `assert` will not execute when `NDEBUG` macro is declared. It is popular to define `NDEBUG` in release builds. Doing expressions with side effects inside `assert` will break on most production environments.

Comment: Thanks a lot however I'm still getting dead lock - changed code :

Comment: in original question

Comment: well, I'm not. Copied your code, removed measure.h and timer_*, compiled with `gcc -Ofast` and run 3 times.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting it - using above code as it is -  it gets stuck in about 50% of cases, so I assume there still some problem.

Comment: But when I added this usage of 
`
assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&list->lock) == 0);
    if (list->head == NULL) {
         assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&list->lock) == 0);
         return rv;
    }
       
    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&list->head->lock) == 0);
    node_t *current = list->head;
    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&list->lock) == 0);
`
So it was some race condition between insert and traversal. 
Dzienkuje bardzo